# Foreach Array only receive last key

Tags: php, laravel-5

This is a first time i get this error ,I have array with 5 element, but when i use Foreach, it's only receive last element. I want to get all key in array $datas['datas'].

```
echo count($datas['datas']);

        [![var_dump($datas['datas']);

        $test = 0;
        foreach ($datas['datas'] as $k => $v);
        {
            echo $k;
            $test++;
        }
        dd($test)];
```

[image]

Comment: What you want to, you need all data in test variable?

Comment: I want to get all key in array.

Comment: See my answer and try, let me know if getting any problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a incorrect ";" character on line 6:

```
foreach ($datas['datas'] as $k => $v);
```

Your code should be:

```
echo count($datas['datas']);
$test = 0;
foreach ($datas['datas'] as $k => $v)
{
    echo $k;
    $test++;
}
dd($test);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are not assigning the value to your variable:

Please replace this loop

```
foreach ($datas\['datas'\] as $k => $v)
{
    echo $k;
    $test++;
}
dd($test);
```

By this:

```
foreach ($datas['datas'] as $k => $v)
{
    echo $k;
    $test['keys'] = $k;
}
dd($test['keys']); // now your full data will be in test variable
```

and Try hoe it will work.